# window.scrollY not working

Tags: javascript, scroll

I've been working on javascript for my website and I just made a little test program. When I check the console, rather than getting the value of `window.scrollY`(y) I get "0" in the console. I use Firefox, just in case that would matter some how. Here is my code:

```
var y = window.scrollY;

console.log(y);
print("foo");

window.onscroll=function(event){

    console.log(y);
}

// used to c#, so I made this a function
                - 
function print(word){

    console.log(word);
}
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing to generate the error, so I would appreciate if I got an answer.

Comment: it is working fine and does not shows any error.

Comment: You're not updating `y` so it'll keep the initial value. Try `console.log(window.scrollY)` inside the scroll listener instead, you'll see it works. Not with IE by the way, that needs `window.pageYOffset`.

Answer (score 3):

This script gives the scrollY position when you scroll

```
window.addEventListener('scroll',()=> console.log(window.scrollY)
)
```

Comment: Can you improve your answer by explaining how your code resolves the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling print() before you declared it. That may be the source of the error. Try removing that line to see if the error goes away.

Comment: I just tried that. Didn't work. Thanks for the help anyways!

Answer (score 1):

you need to give **min-height**  attribute instead of height for body tag. Like the below.

```
min-height: 100vh;
```

or

```
min-height: 100%;
```

It should work then.

Comment: Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) how to use markdown formatting on your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have height:100% in your body tag. Remove it or edit it as 'min-height:100%'.